# Syncing with App Engine tutorial

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am attempting the Syncing with App Engine tutorial in the Resources section of Android Developers.  I installed the GPE, SDKs, set-up a C2DM account, and updated all my software.
The instructions to create and debug the project were straight-forward and easy to follow.
However the generated code has the following warnings: 
"import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException is never used" and 
"import android.accounts.AuthenticatorException is never used".
Is this Okay/normal and can be Ignored?
I am unable to get the generated apps to work together. So now I am just trying to identify and eliminate problems.
Thanks for any help.  Ray

Answer (score 0):

Those warnings just mean that those import statements are unnecessary.  It is safe to remove those warnings by deleting those import lines (or by hitting CMD+SHFT+O or CTRL+SHFT+O to "Organize" your imports).  But that shouldn't cause you any other problems -- you should still be able to build and run despite those warnings.